# I can't understand why it returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I am trying to add 2 to given array. But the code returns undefined when run. I am trying to learn ES6, I couldn't find the problem. I need help.

```
const mapSomething = (arr) => {
  arr.map(n => {
    return n + 2;
    
  })
}

// It have to return [3, 4, 5] but it returns undefined
console.log(mapSomething([1, 2, 3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is logging `undefined` because the function is not returning any value.

You have to return the result from [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const mapSomething = (arr) => {
  return arr.map(n => {
    return n + 2;
  })
}

// It have to return [3, 4, 5] but it returns undefined
console.log(mapSomething([1, 2, 3]));
```

Also take note that the `return` statement in your arrow function is redundant, since there is only one expression being evaluated:

```js
const mapSomething = (arr) => {
  return arr.map(n => n + 2)
}

// It have to return [3, 4, 5] but it returns undefined
console.log(mapSomething([1, 2, 3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `return` statement in the function, so it returns `undefined` by default.

If an arrow function is a single expression that you want to return, you shouldn't put `{}` around it. That makes it a normal function body, which requires an explicit `return` statement (like you have with `n + 2`).

```js
const mapSomething = (arr) => arr.map(n => n + 2);

// It have to return [3, 4, 5] but it returns undefined
console.log(mapSomething([1, 2, 3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const mapSomething = (arr) => {
    const arrData = arr.map(n => {
      return n + 2;     
    })

    return arrData
  }
  
  // It have to return [3, 4, 5] but it returns undefined
  console.log(mapSomething([1, 2, 3]))
  
  //NOTE: you where not returning anything from the function itself
```